# Save graph to blob in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python code that plots a graph in the end. The issue is when I am calling this code with Azure Function, it is not able to plot the graph. So, instead I tried saving the graph on Azure blob storage. But there's no option to upload the graph on blob without saving it loxally on VS Code. And Azure Function doesn't allow to save graph locally.

Is there any way I can upload the graph onto Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Function doesn't allow to save graph locally.

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement by downloading the graph locally using `plt.savefig` and then uploading the .png file to storage account. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import pandas as pd


import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main(myblob: func.InputStream, blobout: func.Out[bytes]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    x=[1,3,5,7]
    y=[2,4,6,1]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig("myimage.png")
    
    with open("myimage.png", "rb") as image:
        f = image.read()
        b = bytearray(f)
        
    blobout.set(b)
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}",
      "connection": "<StorageAccountConnection>"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobout",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "output/myimage.png",
      "connection": "<StorageAccountConnection>",
      "direction": "out"
  }
  ]
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

[image]